# Why is one row in numpy.arrange out of bounds?

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote this code and quite unexpectedly ran into this

```
for i in range(9):
    x = np.arange(i+0.8, i+1.3, 0.1)
    print(i, x)
```

this is output

```
0 [0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2]
1 [1.8 1.9 2.  2.1 2.2]
2 [2.8 2.9 3.  3.1 3.2]
3 [3.8 3.9 4.  4.1 4.2]
4 [4.8 4.9 5.  5.1 5.2]
5 [5.8 5.9 6.  6.1 6.2]
6 [6.8 6.9 7.  7.1 7.2]
7 [7.8 7.9 8.  8.1 8.2 8.3]
8 [8.8 8.9 9.  9.1 9.2]
```

Why is the 7th row like this?

Why exactly in the 7th row?

Comment: A must read: [Is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: `arange` has a warning about using a float step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Adding 0.1 is not a good idea

In general, decimal fractions do not fit nicely into binary floating point formats.

#### Try starting with integers, and then dividing by 10

```
for i in range(9):
    x = np.arange(10*i+8, 10*i+13, 1) / 10
    print(i, x)
```

Result

```
0 [0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2]
1 [1.8 1.9 2.  2.1 2.2]
2 [2.8 2.9 3.  3.1 3.2]
3 [3.8 3.9 4.  4.1 4.2]
4 [4.8 4.9 5.  5.1 5.2]
5 [5.8 5.9 6.  6.1 6.2]
6 [6.8 6.9 7.  7.1 7.2]
7 [7.8 7.9 8.  8.1 8.2]
8 [8.8 8.9 9.  9.1 9.2]
```

Always try to use integers for loop control etc.

You can fudge things for decimals by adding "a little extra" but in general it only leads to hard-to-discover bugs later.

#### Quick demonstration

```
print(0.1+0.2 == 0.3)
```

You might think this should be `True`, but it is `False`.

This is because there is a tiny difference, due to the rounding errors in trying to represent round decimals in binary.

```
print(0.1+0.2 -0.3)
```

> 5.551115123125783e-17

Comment: Look at np.linspace. It knows how to handle the rounding issues and will give you the answer you want.

Comment: Definitely a good idea, more generalisable than just fudging integers.